# Inject a jar file in another jar file

Tags: java

Example: i want to inject the jar file "A.jar" in the jar file "B.jar"

I only know how to inject a method in a jarfile

How can i do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "inject" here? Do you want to package a JAR within another JAR? Do you just want to use classes and methods from another JAR?

Comment: I want to put the source code from the jar file "A.jar" in the jar file "B.jar", do you understand?

Comment: What build tool do you use? With Maven you can e.g. use the maven-assembly-plugin to do that, i'm sure there are solutions with Gradle as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Netbeans + ant. First you create a empty project and put all jars as dependencies of this project. Then you add the target bellow on the build.xml. Go to the "Files" tab, click right the button on the build file and invoke the "package-for-store" target.

```
<target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">

    <!-- Change the value of this property to be the name of your JAR,
         minus the .jar extension. It should not have spaces.
         <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>
    -->
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="mylib"/>


    <!-- don't edit below this line -->

    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
                    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>

    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>

</target>
```

Comment: No, you dont understand what i want. I want a jar with a gui where i can select 2 jars. the first jar should be injected in the second jar

Comment: Maybe if you inspect this template you can have some hint on how to do this.

You will need the Zip Package from Apache Commons for this task.